# Building a PHP application, confused about design patterns

Tags: php

I have been asked to build a PHP application that inserts data into a database and then allows users to run reports on the database.

I have a couple of years of experience of developing in PHP a couple of years ago, but am stuck.

I have read articles about MVC, frameworks, etc... and it all seems to have changed :)

What is the best method to use? I feel like iv been stuck in a time warp and have now come to back to PHP and it has totally changed. Im questioning everything I knew :) I dont even know what directory structure to use to lay the applicaion out :)

I hope someone can help and offer some advice on how to lay applications out what Design principle to use etc...

Please help im totally lost :)

Edit: I would prefer not to have to learn a framework, but rather learn how to build an application. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Guidance, tips/tricks for larger scale php development.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940677/guidance-tips-tricks-for-larger-scale-php-development)

Comment: [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Objects-Patterns-Practice-Experts-Source/dp/143022925X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1288951406&sr=8-1) really helped in getting me up to speed coming from ancient PHP 3 & 4 code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like your thinking. I had a look at CodeIgniter, Cake and the other frameworks and whilst they were good I decided to write my own. I learnt a ton. The first revision of my framework wasn't that great but I have two sites running on that without issues. The second edition of it might not be as mature as Cake etc but it makes building PHP apps a breeze and the key thing for me is: *I know what every line of code does and it's super-quick to change and debug*.

I think the first thing to do is to think about how you are going to break the app into layers, obvious candidates are:

- Front Controller: A class that parses URLs and decides what to do with them. Most frameworks these days use an Apache mod-rewrite rule to forward all URLs to one class - so it's a single entry point into your app.
- Database abstraction layer: Put all of your code that read/writes to a DB in one place and have everything call that. Also known as ORM.
- Models: Classes that represent one or more tables from your DB.
- Controllers: Classes that update/read models, apply logic and populate and show views.
- Views: HTML files that import data from your controllers. I use Smarty.

So taking those elements, you have a basic directory structure:

```
/models
/controllers
/includes
/views
/css
/js
index.php
```

index.php is my Front Controller. And I put ORM stuff and other helper classes for doing generic work like processing forms and stuff into the /includes directory. Obviously /css and /js houses your static javascript and CSS files.

The Front Controller works in that you have URLs that specify which controller to create - something like: www.domain.com/product/1/hello-world. Where product is the name of a class (I call my controllers Controller) - so here my front controller would read the product part of the URL and create an instance of ProductController.

The controllers act upon the rest of the URL that they are given. So ProductController gets params of 1 and hello-world. 1 could be the index of a product to load and display. hello-world is just SEO text to ignore. You could also specify functions to call, so www.domain.com/product/list - this time you create a ProductController and call the list function.

There's different ways to structure a MVC app and forums are full of arguments about it - what I've put above my or may not be true MVC but the main goal is to get good abstraction into your app.

I'd recommend checking out Smarty for your View layer. It's a stable library and provides HTML caching as well.

Comment: Thanks Steve :) very informative and more what I was after :)

Answer (score 2):

First, pick a framework. Then, follow the directory structure it requires and the design principles it uses.

Comment: I dont really want to use a framework :) I jsut see it as total over kill for what I need and not really re-learning php, its rather like learing "the framework language".

Comment: PHP as a language is sufficiently messy and chaotic that you really should be using *some* sort of a framework even if you don't think the application warrants it.

Comment: That would mean im not actually learning how to build a php application, but how to manipulate a framework though? My aim is to learn how to build a full php application, without the need for a framework.

Comment: Then do it 'the old way' because that's exactly what it means to be building an application without a framework (either a ready one, or one that you create)

Comment: Ok, so what about creating a framework?

Comment: You can still get away without frameworks. A framework is just a collection of reusable components. Depends on the project.

Answer (score 2):

Break it down into steps. Think about where code is going to be reusable.

Although I don't use an off-the-shelf framework, I've kind of built one up over the years. Don't be wary of frameworks, they should be embraced.

For example, my framework is pretty simple and lightweight. When I start a project, I create two (sometimes three) directories:

```
cms/
inc/
tpl/
```

They're pretty self-explanatory: **cms** houses a content management system if required; **inc** contains PHP scripts; and **tpl** contains templates and assets such as images, style sheets and JavaScript files giving:

```
cms/
inc/
tpl/
    css/
    img/
    js/
```

I then have an `index.php` file that takes a request (i.e. `http://www.example.com/news/2010/11/05/lorem-ipsum`) which simply passes the request a script that matches the first segment (in the above case `news.php`) and the remaining URL segments are used as parameters. So in my example, to fetch an article matching a date (11 Nov. 2010) and file name (`lorem-ipsum`).

Don't over-engineer things. Plan it first and you'll find with a clear head you'll cut out a load of over-engineering.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your project! PHP is still fun!

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel .. use Zend framework http://framework.zend.com/ , is a best MVC structured you can find. 
Start from their quickstart tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a software engineering question than strictly a PHP question.  There are several software development models.  PHP supports some better than others, but with a little creativity you can implement almost any design.

**[Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller)**

This is the most common architecture that you will probably come across for web platforms.  The idea is to decouple application logic and data from the user interfaces.  This gives the developer the ability to provide multiple interfaces (a mobile interface, one for web services, one for the browser, etc - this all happens in the view layer) while not having to change the core functionality of the application.  The model layer provides the data and (to a point) business logic.  The controller layer couples the model (data) and view (presentation).  The Zend Framework uses MVC, and Django (Python) uses a variant of MVC.

**[Model View Presenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Presenter)**

Like the MVC, the uses a model (data stuff) and view, but the controller is replaced by a presentation component.  The idea behind the presentation component is very similar to the controller, but the difference is that presenter takes away some of the responsibility of the view in MVC.  The view in MVP is strictly for rendering.  The MVP is mainly for heavy UI applications and components.  Windows Forms uses it.

**[Three Tier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-tier_%28computing%29#Three-tier_architecture)**

The three tier system uses a presentation tier, a business logic tier, and a data tier.  The presentation tier handles the incoming requests, outgoing responses, and rendering content.  The business logic tier does the real heavy lifting.  It processes the request and makes decisions based upon those requests.  The data tier consists of the actual data - whether it lives in a database or is a web service from which you grad data.

**[Presentation Abstraction Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation-abstraction-control)**

PAC is like MVC, but a lot more granular, and consists of what is much like little MVC architectures that are all separated from each other.  This one is probably a lot more work than you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks are simply ways of making sure you adopt best practice. But on a small project, you can quite easily adopt good practice without a framework. All you need is a class or set of functions which do all the interaction with your database. These will generate the SQL queries based on the parameters you pass them. Then all the non-database logic should be kept separate. Optionally, you can make a class or set of functions to handle the viewing code (the bit that actually generates your HTML) and another to handle the bits in between, but if you're getting to this level of MVC complexity, you'd be much quicker just learning a framework.

Answer (score 0):

I really do know how you feel.

I am an old school guy and I think I'm a little resilient with all those new stuff. I just can't use a tool without know exactly what is happening.

Sorry for frameworks evangelists, and megaproductive developers. I think when you use a framework, a CMS, or design patterns you miss all the fun. Studying them worth a while. Just using them is not a so good thing IMHO.

Well, these days we hear a lot about OOP, design patterns, and so on. Learning those things can worth. But as said by @Martin Bean, *"don't over-engineering"*. PHP will perform the same, probably even better if you do it structured (includes, requires, functions). You can use "new" resources progressively, learning their basis as they makes sense and you feel more comfortable.

Take the safe path. Do application as you know to do, and try to learn one or two new things.

Answer (score 0):

How Rasmus Lerdorf (co-creator of PHP) does it, "The no-framework PHP MVC Framework": http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/38-The-no-framework-PHP-MVC-framework.html